# several Handlers for the UI Thread

Tags: android, android-handler, android-looper

According to [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui#java):

> All of the Handler objects for a particular thread receive the same
>   message.

However in this code:

```
Handler h1 = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
Handler h2 = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
h1.post(runnable1);
h2.post(runnable2);
h1.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
```

`runnable2` gets executed although all callbacks were removed for `h1`.

Also, `h1.equals(h2)` returns `false`.

Should an application use just one `Handler` for the main thread?

Answer (score 1):

So, for `h1.equals(h2)` returning `false` the explanation is very simple - `Handler` class does not override `equals`, so they are being compared by identity, and as `h1` and `h2` are two distinct objects, it returns `false`.

Regarding as to why `runnable2` gets executed:
These two Handlers have same underlying Looper, and so they have the same underlying message queue. Posting a runnable internally enqueues a message with a Runnable you posted to Handler and this Handler as a target for this message.

When you call `removeCallbacksAndMessages(null)`, `Handler` requests message queue to remove all the messages that has itself as a target. So in your case the queue will have two messages:
1) Message which will run `runnable1` and target `h1`
2) Message which will run `runnable2` and target `h2`

And thus when you call `h2.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null)`, the message queue will only remove the messages that were posted from `h2`.

Because of that, there's no sense in trying to have only one Handler for the main thread - in fact, it can be counterproductive if you have multiple `Runnable` posters, but only want to cancel some of them.